# Execute a Google Compute Engine script from a webpage?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is it possible to run a script sitting on one of the Google Compute Engines from a webpage?

I am developing an internal dashboard for our company and one of the requirements is to be able to run a script sitting on the compute engine via a button.

Is this possible? How can I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google compute engine instances are virtual servers, so yes you can easily do that.

Create a simple server application listening for requests from your web page(using your favorite server-side technology, such as nodejs, php, java, ...) and run the script from your listener app.